# Riemann series theorem - when can I be sure that my series diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $a_i$ with both positive and negative values.

I managed to prove that it is possible to group the elements to infinitely many groups such that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}a_i = \sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n_2}a_i = \sum_{i=n_2+1}^{n_3}a_i =... = d$$

where $d$ is some positive number. From that, I wanted to conclude that the infinite sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i = +\infty$.

But, then I recalled the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) that says that, if an infinite series converges but the series of its absolute values diverges, it is possible to rearrange the elements such that the sum can be any value, finite or infinite.

So, what more should I do in order to correctly prove that the sum is infinite?

Comment: If you can show that there is a $b$ such that $$\sum_{i = n_k + 1}^{n_{k+1}} a_i^- \leqslant b$$ for all $k$, that would be sufficient. (Here, $x^- = \max \{ -x, 0\}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @AlexR. in my case, $d>0$. So, apparently, if there are infinitely many groupings, then the sum is equivalent to $d+d+d+...$ infinitely many times, which is $\infty$.

Comment: If we have $1<n_1<n_2<n_3<\dots$, then by the limit of the partial sums, $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^na_i=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}a_i$$iff it exists.  If not, then the sum doesn't exist.